# A Complex sql Query suggesion

Tags: sql

I am building an application

I have a Student table in my SQL database 
this has the following structure

```
(
Student_ID int,
FullName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar(255),
FatherName varchar(255),
Father_FirstName varchar(255),
Father_LastName varchar(255),
Date_of_Birth datetime,
Gender varchar(10),
Date_of_Registration datetime,
Regestration_Status varchar(10),
Degree_Status varchar(10),
Qualification varchar(15),
Campus varchar(15),
Batch int,
Degree varchar(10)
)
```

The data gathered in this table is from 4 different cities KARACHI,ISLAMABAD,PESHAWAR,KARACHI

Students data gathered from Peshawar do not have the Gender property set and so in this whole table Gender column for those students who are from peshawar does not contain any value.

my supervisor has asked me to fill this patch of the table through association rule, that is mostly students name are quite similar through out the table and if there is a particular name such as "USMAN" and there are 100 names like USMAN in the whole table regardless of the city they are from if 60 USMAN rows have the gender MALE then any row in the patch where peshawar is the city and the name of the student is Usman i should set its gender to Male

I hope i have made clear my problem i am trying to make this work through some sql query if any one can help me i will be very thank ful

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Can you give a sample result? Can two students have the same father, or more than one degree? If so, you should normalize the table.

Comment: If I understand well, you want, for each firstname, to get the most represented gender, and from this data, update gender of people with the same firstname and null gender with this gender ? On which DB engine do you work on ?

Comment: Yes Sir exactly that is what i am trying to do i am using SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 0):

This is a good trick for setting the gender column.  First start by summarizing by first name:

```
select FirstName, count(*), sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as NumMales,
       avg(case when gender = 'M' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as MalePercent,
       (case when avg(case when gender = 'M' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) > 0.5 then 'M'
             else 'F'
        end) as ImputedGender
from Students s
where gender is not null
group by FirstName
```

Next, you need to look over the results and set a cutoff.  A single male or female student with a particular name is not convincing that that name assigns the gender.  So, say you need at least five examples and 80% in one gender:

```
select FirstName, count(*), sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as NumMales,
       avg(case when gender = 'M' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as MalePercent,
       (case when avg(case when gender = 'M' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) > 0.5 then 'M'
             else 'F'
        end) as ImputedGender
from Students s
where gender is not null
group by FirstName
having count(*) >= 5 and
       avg(case when gender = 'M' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) not between 0.2 and 0.8
```

The next step is to assign the imputed gender to the rows.  That may depend on the variety of SQL.  This is something like:

```
update Students
    set gender = ImputedGender
    from (<the above query>) ig
    where ig.Firstname = Students.FirstName and
          Students.city <> 'Peshawar' and
          Students.gender is null
```

Comment: Dear Gordon thank u very much but i am new to SQL These are really complex queries u have written i am trying to dry run this in my mind to understand this